# Opencart 2.x.x. cart to enquiry basket

Tags: quote

I am a newbie on opencart. I want to change the working of cart button. Actually, i dont want to show the prices of my products instead i want my customers to contact me for quote.

So, i want my cart button work in a way that when user click on checkout button, a form open (instead of paypal) in which cart added product names and ID written with other fields like name, email etc so that the user can get a quote from me.

I also want to change the add to cart text to add to basket and checkout text to Get Qoute.

Please help me, i know my issue is very complex and large. And i also know that you can do that.

Comment: You need to provide more information, what have you done so far etc, where is your code?

Comment: i have no code.... want to modify opencart 2.o.1.1